# 'fname' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net

```
Protected Sub btnAddSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddSubmit.Click
 Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO account(firstname, lastname, uname, pass, type)" & " VALUES ('" & fname.Value.ToString &
 "','" & lname.Value.ToString & "','" & username.Value.ToString & "','"
 & password.Value.ToString & "','" & Type.Value.ToString & "')"



Protected Sub btnDeleteSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteSubmit.Click
 Dim SQLStatement As String = "DELETE FROM account WHERE firstname, lastname, uname, pass, type = ('" & fname.Value.ToString &
  "','" & lname.Value.ToString & "','" & username.Value.ToString & "','"
  & password.Value.ToString & "','" & Type.Value.ToString & "') WHERE
  username='" & username.Value.ToString & "'"
```

All the fname.Value.ToString, lname.Value.ToString, uname.Value.ToString, password.Value.ToString, type.Value.ToString is showing an error of

> is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

These are textbox

Comment: Is this aspx? Did you set the `runat="server"` for those textboxes

Comment: well that worked thanks silly me :(

Comment: the error came back D: after a few debugging

Comment: It should not change after a few runs, check your work.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549325/is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `runat="server"` for those textboxes in the markup.