# is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net

```
Protected Sub btnAddSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddSubmit.Click
    Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO account(firstname, lastname, uname, pass, type)" & " VALUES ('" & fname.Value.ToString & "','" & lname.Value.ToString & "','" & username.Value.ToString & "','" & password.Value.ToString & "','" & Type.Value.ToString & "')"
    SaveNames(SQLStatement)
    fname.Value = ""
    lname.Value = ""
    username.Value = ""
    password.Value = ""
    Type.Value = ""
```

All the fname.Value.ToString, lname.Value.ToString, uname.Value.ToString, password.Value.ToString, type.Value.ToString is showing an error of

> is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

These are textbox

```
        <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input runat="server" id="fname" type="text" placeholder="Firstname">
    </div>
    <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input runat="server" id="lname" type="text" placeholder="Lastname">
    </div>
    <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="name">Username</label>
        <input runat="server" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input runat="server" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546891/fname-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `.Text` property instead of 'value'

```
fname.Text = ""
...
```

Answer (score -1):

If the code behind class is not declared public, try making that public.

Comment: Is this it, sorry im new at programming                                                        Public Class manage_account
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim con As MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim dat As MySqlDataReader
    Dim ServerString As String = "Server=localhost;Database=database23;Uid=root;Pwd=;"
    Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

Comment: This is not his problem.